# For a Zend form, how can I update the end date to automatically be one day after the start date when a start date is entered?

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework

I have a start date element and an end date element in a form. Each are selected using a datepicker. I would like my form to automatically set the end date element of my form to be one day after the start date is selected (so, for example, if I select July 10, 2013, the value in the end date field should default to July 11, 2013). The user can make the end date whatever they want to from then on, but initially it should be the day after.

Here is my code for the form:

```
    // Element: start_date
    $start_date = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('start_date',
        array(
             'label' => 'Start date',
             'required' => false,
             'filters' => array('StringTrim', 'StripTags'),
             'class' => 'input-small datepicker',
             'decorators' => $customElementDecorators,
             'data-date' => date("Y-m-d"),
             'data-date-format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd',
             'value' => date("Y-m-d")
        )
    );

    // date validator
    $start_date->addValidator(new Zend_Validate_Date('Y-m-d'));

    $this->addElement($start_date);
    unset($start_date);

    // Element: end_date
    $end_date = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('end_date',
        array(
             'label' => 'End date',
             'required' => false,
             'filters' => array('StringTrim', 'StripTags'),
             'class' => 'input-small datepicker',
             'decorators' => $customElementDecorators,
             'data-date' => date("Y-m-d"),
             'data-date-format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd',
             'value' => date("Y-m-d")
        )
    );
    $this->addElement($end_date);
    unset($end_date);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `'value' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 day'));`

Comment: when you say "selected" you mean the user is the one who selects a date, and that´s when you want the "end date" set? Are you using jquery datepicker?

Answer (score 1):

You absolutely need to use Javascript (or Jquery ...there is a nice plugin: http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/ ) to perform a such action in "real time". other solution is to check date after Post action and display customized error message.

Answer (score 0):

When you set the data-date property for the end assign it the value of `date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day"));`

```
$end_date = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('end_date',
    array(
         'label' => 'End date',
         'required' => false,
         'filters' => array('StringTrim', 'StripTags'),
         'class' => 'input-small datepicker',
         'decorators' => $customElementDecorators,
         'data-date' => date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day")),
         'data-date-format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd',
         'value' => date("Y-m-d")
    )
);
```